# Soql check if related record exist

Tags: soql, custom-object, sobject

I am using two sobjects Work__c  with field name and WorkAssign__c with name,freeze__c and Work__c master-detail to Works sobject. Upd:
So i want to get first Work__c record which doesnt related to WorkAssign__c or related and where clause works

```
Select name from Work__c where id = (Select work__c from WorkAssign__c WHERE Freeze__c = false ) ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a semi-join (a subquery in the `WHERE` clause), it sounds like you'd be better served by a parent-child subquery (a subquery in the `SELECT` clause).

That allows you to keep the amount of processing down, though the more important part is that you're still only using a single query (the subquery counts towards a separate "aggregate queries" limit, which we're allowed to use 300 in a given transaction).

parent-child subqueries return results as `List<SObject>` embedded in each parent record. There are some considerations to keep in mind when trying to access that embedded list if you have enough child records, but in the end your check to see if there are any child records boils down to calling `isEmpty()` on a List.

```java
for(Work__c workRecord :[
            SELECT 
                Name,
                /* 
                    Note that you need to use the child relationship name here
                    That's usually just the plural of the object name + __r (instead of
                    __c)
                */
                (SELECT Name FROM WorkAssigns__r) 
            FROM 
                Work__c 
            ORDER BY NAME]){
    List<WorkAssign__c> childRecords = new List<WorkAssign__c>();

    // Accessing the embedded list requires you to use the child relationship name
    // This nested for-loop is the safe (and generally recommended) approach to working
    //   with child records from a subquery
    // Nested for loops aren't inherently evil, and are generally required when you
    //   have nested data
    for(WorkAssign__c childRec :workRecord.WorkAssigns__r){
        childRecords.add(childRec);
    }

    // Checking if a given record has any children is simple
    system.debug(childRecords.isEmpty());

    // In cases where you have fewer than 200 child records for _every_ queried parent
    //   you should be able to avoid the nested for loop and access the embedded list
    //   directly (and all of the other code in this loop could be removed or commented out
    //system.debug(workRecord.WorkAssigns__r.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: Seems good, thanks, but how can i check some fields in WorkAssign__c  ? Sorry if u start answer until i edited question,

Comment: And actually that way tells me if  there are any children records? I need it for every record.

Comment: @jeltaboknu You can filter subquery results with the `WHERE` clause just like a normal query. The major difference between your query and my query is just that I moved your subquery out of the `WHERE` clause and into the `SELECT` clause. When you perform a parent-child subquery, the embedded `List<SObject>` will never be null (it will either be empty or contain some record(s)). The parent-child subquery groups child records by parent, so if `workRecord.WorkAssigns__r` is empty, then that specific `Work__c` record has no child records (or doesn't have any that meet the criteria in the `WHERE`)